# Using regex to only retrieve string with 7 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In short, the page contains about 10 divs, each containing letters and numbers and I'm trying to return all occurrences of exactly 7 digits, but can have other, non-digit characters before and after.

eg.

"q1234567" should return 1234567

"q1234567q" should return 1234567

"q1234567q1234567q12345678q" should return 1234567 and 1234567

"12345678" should NOT be returned

To be more specific, an example of an entire string:

```
q1234567q
q1234567q
q12345678q
q1234567q123456789q123456q1324567q1234567
1234567
1
12
123
1234
12345
q12345q
q1234
12345q
123
```

I tried doing this via regex and got as far as

```
/\d{7}(?=\D|$)/g
```

but JavaScript doesn't play well with the lookbehind.. How can I get around this without involving a whole new library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use something like this?

```
var regex = /(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?!\d)/g;
var s = "q1234567q123456789q123456q1324567q1234567";
var match, matches=[];

while ( (match=regex.exec(s)) !== null ) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

alert(matches);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbf74/)

Comment: This seems to be have resolved it! Thank you. Care to explain how using exec() rather than match() makes the difference?

Comment: @user3258911 `match` ends when it found a match and will return all matches: the whole match and all sub-matches when `g` is off and all whole matches when `g` is on. `exec` on the other hand matches up to a point, and when you call it again, it tries to match as from the point its match ended earlier. That enables the code to obtain each of the sub-matches each time there is one match and still find all matches.

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work:

```
/^\D*\d{7}\D*$/
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nE5eI6

**UPDATE:** As per edited question and comments below you can use this regex:

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?=\D|$)
```

And use *matched group #1* for your output.

#### Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wL4oW1

Comment: It only works if there is exactly 7 digits on the entire line. Which is not necessarily the case, see edit

Comment: +1, not for the answer, but for using regex101. i didn't know about this, that is new to me.

Comment: @user3258911: What should be return value for `q1234567q123456789q123456q1324567q1234567`?

Comment: Can you also include your expected output in the question with latest edited input strings.

Comment: @anubhava It should be as stated, ever occurrence of exactly 7 digits in a line. So 1234567, 1324567 and 1234567

Comment: Ok can you try: `(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?=\D|$)` and take `group #1`

Answer (score 0):

What about: `(?<=\D)[0-9]{7}(?=\D|$)|^[0-9]{7}(?=\D|$)`?

Comment: JavaScript still doesn't play well with lookbehind.

Comment: Just use a capture group then and `.exec` rather than `.match` and grab `matches[i][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /(\b|\D)(\d{7})(\b|\D)/g
function get7digits(s) {
    var md, matches=[];
    while( (md=regex.exec(s)) !== null ) matches.push(md[2]);
    return matches;
}

get7digits('q1234567q123456789q123456q1324567q1234567')
```

> ["1234567", "1324567"]

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

`/(^|\D)\d{7}(\$|\D)/gm`

http://regex101.com/r/iT5cR3

Comment: So close, however it messes up in a string like this: q1234567q123456789q123456q1324567q1234567q1234567